# Trying to get category name from url

Tags: low-seg2cat

i have a url domain.com/index.php/washington/4 where 4 is category_id. I have only one category group and i try to use Low Seg2cat.

I need to get {segment_2} to display the title of category name (and nothing else) like

Title: {segment_2_category_name}

Is that possible? Itried but no success.

Any ideas please?

Comment: {segment_2_category_name} is possible if you use category URL tilte in url segment instead of category ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mufi correctly commented, [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) uses category **URL titles**, not category IDs.